# Sales Order page Button not showing

Tags: magento-1.9

**Config.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Manoj_Csv>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Manoj_Csv>
  </modules>
  <global>
   <adminhtml>
        <events>
            <adminhtml_widget_container_html_before>
                <observers>
                    <manoj_csv>
                        <class>csv/observer</class>
                        <method>adminhtmlWidgetContainerHtmlBefore</method>
                    </manoj_csv> 
                </observers>
            </adminhtml_widget_container_html_before>
        </events>
    </adminhtml>
  </global>
</config>
```

**observer.php**

```
<?php

Class Manoj_Csv_Model_Observer
{
    public function adminhtmlWidgetContainerHtmlBefore($event)
    {
        $block = $event->getBlock();
        $message = Mage::helper('sales')->__('Are you want to Download...?');

        if ($block instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View) {
            $block->addButton('do_something_crazy', array(
                'label'     => Mage::helper('Sales')->__('Download...'),
                'onclick'   => "confirmSetLocation('{$message}','{$block->getUrl('*/')}')", // < missed comma
                'class'     => 'go'
            ));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:
observer name should be in lower case (start and end tags)

```
    <adminhtml>
        <events>
            <adminhtml_widget_container_html_before>
                <observers>
                    <zerobars_approvebutton>
                        <class>test_module/observer</class>
                        <method>adminhtmlWidgetContainerHtmlBefore</method>
                    </zerobars_approvebutton> <!-- should be lowercase here-->
                </observers>
            </adminhtml_widget_container_html_before>
        </events>
    </adminhtml>
```

Missed "," in observer and unexisting `$this->getUrl()`:

```
    public function adminhtmlWidgetContainerHtmlBefore($event)
    {
        $block = $event->getBlock();
        $message = Mage::helper('sales')->__('Are you sure you want to Change Status?');

        if ($block instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View) {
            $block->addButton('do_something_crazy', array(
                'label'     => Mage::helper('Sales')->__('Download...'),
                'onclick'   => "confirmSetLocation('{$message}','{$block->getUrl('*/')}')", // < missed comma; use $block->getUrl() instead $this->getUrl()
                'class'     => 'go'
            ));
        }
    }
```

Result (it works fine):

[image: Result with observer]

If you still get errors, try to replace the class call `<class>csv/observer</class>` with the `<class>Manoj_Csv_Model_Observer</class>` or with the `<class>manoj_csv/observer</class>`

Complete config.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Manoj_Csv>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Manoj_Csv>
    </modules>
    <global>
    </global>
    <adminhtml>
        <events>
            <adminhtml_widget_container_html_before>
                <observers>
                    <manoj_csv>
                        <class>Manoj_Csv_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>adminhtmlWidgetContainerHtmlBefore</method>
                    </manoj_csv>
                </observers>
            </adminhtml_widget_container_html_before>
        </events>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

Comment: Check my updated question what i missed

Comment: @Kothari try change <class>csv/observer</class> to <class>Manoj_Csv_Model_Observer</class> or to <class>manoj_csv/observer</class>

Comment: I tried but not working

Comment: @Kothari It's strange, becouse it works fine for me

Comment: Ok i will check my end

Comment: @Kothari oh, please move adminhtml section outside the global section

Comment: @Kothari I've updated my answer (see the complete config.xml at end)